# How to change the logo of a child page on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Header.php

```
<div class="site-branding">
        <div class="container">
            <?php

            ***if ( is_page('/category/fitness/') ) ?>{
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?> /assets/images/fitnesslogo.jpg" 
width="100" height="100"/>
}***
<?php
            if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) ) {
                the_custom_logo();
            }

            if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( 
home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( 
'/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
            <?php
            endif;

            $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
            if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
                <p class="site-description"><?php echo $description; /* 
WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
            <?php
            endif; ?>
            <?php do_action('boston_after_site_description'); ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .site-branding -->
```

The page slug is /category/fitness as the URL on the end of the page suggests when I go to the page it looks like it's not interpreting the img src, but is displaying '{}' tags that are around the img scr instead

Comment: So you want the logo change to affect only one page? It would help to know what theme you are using.

Comment: Yes, exactly that. I'm using a theme called Boston.

Comment: the logo is set in the file `header.php` of the theme.

Comment: I've added some code where I believe the log is being set, where would I change the logo or a specific page?

Comment: I've updated  the code to what I think the correct syntax should be, now it's just displaying the { } brackets around the img src and looks like it's not actually handling the image itself

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
           ***if ( is_page('/category/fitness/') ) ?>{
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?> /assets/images/fitnesslogo.jpg" 
width="100" height="100"/>
}***
```

But it should be

```
if ( is_page('/category/fitness/') ) {
    echo '<img src="'.bloginfo('template_url').'/assets/images/fitnesslogo.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Boston theme, but it looks like it's checking to see if a custom logo has been added and if so to use it. So, I would think the following would give you what you're looking for.

```
    <?php if ( is_page('/category/fitness/') ) : ?>
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/images/fitnesslogo.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
    <?php else : ?>
        if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) ) {
            the_custom_logo();
        }
```